# Sudo permissions mixed up

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I was messing with ubuntu trying to make autogen.sh work and did a dumb thing. I typed:

```
sudo chown -R emilia /usr/bin/
```

and after that I cannot use sudo anymore.

I tried so far:

logging as root and typing:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Didn't help.

I ran some tests and here are the results:

```
emilia@emilia:~$ ls -la /usr/bin | grep -v "root *root"
total 147656
drwxr-xr-x  2 emilia root      65536 Aug 14 16:06 .
-rwxr-xr-x  1 emilia root      51920 Feb 18 14:37 [
lrwxrwxrwx  1 emilia root          8 Aug  7 16:04 2to3 -> 2to3-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 emilia root         96 Jul  2 21:02 2to3-2.7

emilia@tenshi:~$ ls -la /usr/bin | grep -v "rwxr-xr-x\|^l"
total 147656
-rwxrwxr-x  1 emilia emilia       22 Aug 14 16:06 autogen.sh

emilia@emilia:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 emilia root 136808 Maj  4 19:25 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: Are you sure you ran the commands you say as root? Were there any errors? What happened? The `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo` should have at least fixed the permissions and ownership of the `sudo` binary.

Comment: @terdon yes I was sure, I entered root by restarting, entering advanced ubuntu settings, root and then I entered those commands. No errors were shown.

Comment: could you please do the same thing again and show us the output of your ls commands run as root?

Comment: @terdon https://postimg.org/image/5gw0yc4d5/

Comment: there we go, that's what I thought. You see the error messages about read only file system? You need to remount it read write. Run `mount -o rw,remount /` before attempting to fix the permissions.

Comment: At least you didn't do `sudo chown -R emilia /`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you cannot use `sudo` anymore, there are two things you can do:

1. If you have placed a root password (not your user password), use `su` on a terminal and you will be able to use the root account by using that password.
2. If you haven't placed a root password, you can reboot your system and go to **Recovery mode**, and open a **root** session.  Since you haven't placed a root password you won't be asked to enter one.  After that, type: `mount -o rw,remount /` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enable read/write access to your system.

Having gained root access by either of the methods above, issue `chown -R root:root /usr/bin` and you should be back to business.

Comment: That did the trick.

Comment: Very nice. You will probably have to restore some permissions now since you changed them but having root access now, that won't be an issue.  ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Your commands are not working because [recovery mode mounts the file system as read-only](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/friendly-recovery/+bug/996454). To make it writable, run this command:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Now, execute:

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chown -R root:root /usr/bin
```

to fix the permissions.